# Pipe has come out of the silencer?

Tags: engine, exhaust, mitsubishi, muffler

I hit a pothole this morning on my way to work. I couldn't swerve it so slowed right down but it still sounded painful!

Afterwards the car was making a boy racer type noise, so took it to the garage and they told me the pipe has come out of the silencer. Only Mitsubishi can fix this for me and will cost approx £2000

I just wondered if anyone can tell me anymore about this and what needs to be done?

I know nothing at all about cars but want to know if I am being ripped off!

Thanks :-)

Comment: Hi Bex, welcome to the site. Could you tell us what the model and year of your car is? £2000 sounds like a lot of money for an exhaust.

Comment: Also note that if you can prove it was the pothole that caused the damage, and the council knew about it, you can claim from them for the cost of repairing it - it's very difficult to prove though...

Comment: Mitsubishi outlander. 2008. yes I will definitely try to claim back!

Comment: Google suggests that a rear silencer for a 2008 Outlander should cost around £60 + fitting - assuming that's the only bit that's failed. Even a full system should be well under £1k - I'd expect £600 or so. (assuming UK prices as you quoted £ in the question). Take it to another garage, or an exhaust specialist, for a second opinion!